# Custom python dictionary accepting both string and enums as keys

Tags: python, dictionary, enums

I want to create a dictionary that would store its keys as string variables, 
but would still be able to retrieve its values using enums.

The reason for that is that my code is sharing this dictionary with other programs and processes, by saving it into a database and by sending it to other applications using REST. In order to make it easier to manage the dictionary itself, I would like the keys to be of type string. However, I would appreciate it if I would be able to get values by enums.

I don't want to access values simply by using strings since that would be using "magic strings".
The option of constants variables is just ugly, and it seems like enum is the nicest solution to this problem. That being said, I don't want it to use the `.value` each time because it makes the code longer and uglier.

Is it possible to add support for both strings and enums?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would need to override the `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` methods in order to support both string and enum types.
Your goal is to get the method's parameter and cast it into a string if it's an enum. That way would be able to retrieve and store string values using the enum variable.

Your code supposes to look like that:

```py
from collections import UserDict
from enum import Enum


class EnumDict(UserDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        string_key = key.value if isinstance(key, Enum) else key
        super().__setitem__(string_key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        string_item = item.value if isinstance(item, Enum) else item
        return super().__getitem__(string_item)
```

Pay attention that this would work only if you actually inherit from `UserDict`.
Please read this excellent blog post "[The problem with inheriting from dict and list in Python](https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/)" in order to understand why I'm using `UserDict` instead of a regular `dict`. Otherwise, you would need to override `__init__`, `update`, and `get` methods too.

Pay attention that if you're using python2 (which you shouldn't since it is no longer supported) the above code won't work because `UserDict` is used as a backward compatibility thing for the time in which you couldn't inherit directly from `dict`. It does not have the same set of features and capabilities as in python3.

Anyway, if you're using python2 or just don't want to inherit from `UserDict`, 
this is what your code should look like:

```py
from enum import Enum


class EnumDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            for key, value in args[0].items():
                self.__setitem__(key, value)
        except Exception:
            super().update(*args, *kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        string_key = key.value if isinstance(key, Enum) else key
        super().__setitem__(string_key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        string_item = item.value if isinstance(item, Enum) else item
        return super().__getitem__(string_item)

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        string_key = key.value if isinstance(key, Enum) else key
        return super().get(string_key, default)
```

To sum things up, the whole idea here is to cast enum into its string value.
When using `dict` and not `UserDict`, one should also take care of the 
initialization, update and regular get processes - making sure you won't get 
stuck with enums instead of regular strings.

Here is an example of how this dictionary works:

```py
In [1]: class Test(Enum): 
   ...:     A = "abc" 
   ...:     B = "xyz" 
   ...:     C = "qwerty"

In [2]: my_dict = EnumDict({"ok": "fine", Test.B: "bla-bla"})                   

In [3]: my_dict                                                                 
Out[3]: {'ok': 'fine', 'xyz': 'bla-bla'}

In [4]: my_dict[Test.A] = "hello"                                               

In [5]: my_dict["testing"] = "works"                                            

In [6]: my_dict                                                                 
Out[6]: {'ok': 'fine', 'xyz': 'bla-bla', 'abc': 'hello', 'testing': 'works'}

In [7]: my_dict.update({"isOkay": "yes", Test.B: "wow"})                        

In [8]: my_dict                                                                 
Out[8]: {'ok': 'fine', 'xyz': 'wow', 'abc': 'hello', 'testing': 'works', 'isOkay': 'yes'}

In [9]: my_dict.get(Test.C, "does not exist")                                  
Out[9]: 'does not exist'

In [10]: my_dict.get(Test.A)                                                    
Out[10]: 'hello'

In [11]: my_dict[Test.A]                                                        
Out[11]: 'hello'

In [12]: my_dict["xyz"]                                                         
Out[12]: 'wow'
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine your `Enum` with `str`, then each member will be a string as well as an `Enum` and you can use a normal dict:

```
class Test(str, Enum):
    A = "abc"
    B = "xyz"
    C = "qwerty"

my_dict = {"ok": "fine", Test.B: "bla-bla"}
```

The only difference is the display of the dict when an `Enum` member is the key:

```
>>> my_dict
{'ok': 'fine', <Test.B: 'xyz'>: 'bla-bla'}
```

But it still works just fine:

```
>>> my_dict['xyz']
'bla-bla'

>>> my_dict[Test.B]
'bla-bla'
```